# How to trigger WFFM exception

Tags: wffm

Using sc8.u3 with WFFM 8.2u3

I'm encrypting form data on submit. When there is an exception, I would like to show the error message but here, it always shows the success message.

```
public override void InsertFormData(FormData form)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(form, "form");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(form.Fields, "form.Fields");

            try
            {
                form.Fields = EncryptFields(form.Fields);

                if (form.Fields != null)
                {
                    base.InsertFormData(form);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Log.Error("Exception: " + ex.Message, this);
                throw;              
            }
}
```

Comment: Which type of error you expect to catch? And could you provide your error from Sitecore log file?

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou. There are no errors in log file, and I'm not sure of what exceotions may occur. I just want to show the error message to end user when there is an exception. In current case, it always shows success message

Comment: @Qwerty you are doing everything right.  Sitecore WFFM actions work in next way: if any exception is thrown then error message on is displayed. You can configure error messages on "Error messages" tab of "Save actions" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return your error message to user, you need to have `ErrorMessage` text field on your form,then get `FormData form`, find this `ErrorMessage` field and add your error message there.
Also you need to wrap your logic:

```
public override void InsertFormData(FormData form)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(form, "form");
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(form.Fields, "form.Fields");

            try
            {
                form.Fields = EncryptFields(form.Fields);

                if (form.Fields != null)
                {
                    base.InsertFormData(form);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Log.Error("Exception: " + ex.Message, this);
                throw new Exception("Error Message");              
            }
}
```

If it not help, try to do step by step [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957098/sitecorewffm-custom-error-message-with-details-on-same-page-with-form) suggestion

Comment: Even if i read the message from the text field, Sitecore is ignoring that exception and considers form submit as success. So it hides the form and shows the success message. Right?